# _.keys not finding every Item shown in Firebug

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebug

I have a post, saved to $scope.mydata in the controller. I give this data via a parameter to a service that returns a function.

The service:

```
module.factory('myservice', function () {
    return function servicefunction(mydata) {
        var test = _.keys(mydata).length;
        console.log("mydata", mydata);
        console.log("test", test);
```

**Firebug** in **Firefox** shows me in the dom that `mydata` contains:

```
Object { $$state={...},  angularCollection=false,  $object={...},  mehr...}
```

and the test returns 5.

When I type

```
module.factory('myservice', function () {
    return function servicefunction(mydata) {
        var test = _.keys(mydata.$$state).length;
        console.log("mydata", mydata.$$state);
        console.log("test", test);
```

Firebug gives me the `Object { status=0}` and in the DOM there is status and `value []`. I need to get access to that `value`. The test returns 1 for the status.

Why test via _.keys finding the status but not the value?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the DOM there is…"? Be noted that `_.keys` will give you own enumerable properties of your object, but not inherited properties. So if `value` comes from the prototype, it will not be listed by `_.keys`.

Comment: means, when I click on the "Object { status=0}", there is status and value. When I do :  var keysInState = _.keys(mydata.$$state); or  var mapInState = _.map(mydata.$$state); there is just "status" in keys and a [0] for the map

Comment: You can try the `hasOwnProperty` method to test if a property is inherited from a prototype, or if it has been defined for your object. What does `mydata.$$state.hasOwnProperty(value)` outputs in your case? If it is `true`, then there is a problem as it should have been listed by `_.keys` indeed. If it is `false`, that means the `value` property is inherited, and `_.keys` is **degined** to ignore it.

Comment: mydata.$$state.hasOwnProperty() returns false, in mydata.$$state.hasOwnProperty(value), it craches, beacuse 'value is not defined'

Comment: My bad, should have been `mydata.$$state.hasOwnProperty("value")`

Comment: okay, it´s still false. hm the post-method returns the values for sure, because i can see them in firebug. any idea how to get to these values?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access a property (`value`) that is inherited from your `mydata.$$state`'s *prototype*. In that case, using `_.keys` will never list `value`.

It may very well be that it is inherited for now because it is empty, and it will become an *own* property once it is set.

Why not simply accessing it like so: `mydata.$$state.value`? It should work for both cases (inherited and *owned*).

I may lack a major part of your context, so if it still does not work, it would be worth providing more information about your data.

Comment: mydata.$$state.value gives me a undefined. okay, so the problem has to be made before. I´m just wondering why Firebug shows me the value without access to it. I got the mydata from a post-request and giving it via a parameter to the service, I´m in right now. Is the value now already a part of mydata or not?